# Why is it rendering twice before I get the final rendering?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

Is that normal? The last time I checked it, it was near 100% rendering, now it's at 4% as you can see. Why is it starting again?

Answer (score 3):

The possible chances are that, either you might have clicked on render animation, which is present under the Render menu, or you might have multiple passes in view layers or in simply you are rendering passes.